# How to sum JSON objects data in Rails using after_save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, after-save

I'm storing daily orders inside daily_orders table. Inside that table, I've `total` column and `special_kitchen_orders` column (type: JSON).

Right now, when I run this into my console:

```
ap DailyOrder.first.special_kitchen_orders
```

I get this back:

```
[
    [0] {
         "name" => "pizza",
          "qty" => 1,
        "price" => 10
    },
    [1] {
         "name" => "burger",
          "qty" => 1,
        "price" => 20
    },
    [2] {
         "name" => "cake",
          "qty" => 1,
        "price" => 30
    }
]
```

I was thinking to use [after_save](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save) to calculate sum of all objects price but I've no idea how to make it.

In this example, the `total` should be `60` (10 + 20 + 30).

How to sum all objects price after saving the record and put it inside the `total` column using `after_save`?

**Note**: `ap` is from [awesome_print gem](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print).

**SOLVED**

I just found the idea after reading [this article](http://nishacodes.tumblr.com/post/80652377352/using-reduce-aka-inject-in-ruby). Thanks Sergio Tulentsev for pointing this `reduce` thing to me. It's totally new thing for me.

```
def total(array)
  array.reduce(0) do |sum, num|
    sum += num
  end
end


total([1,2,3])
# => 6
```

Comment: What would the sum of those objects be?

Comment: It should be `60` for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as this

```
special_kitchen_orders.reduce(0) do |memo, order| 
  memo + order['qty'] * order['price']
end
```

Also you might want to do this in a `before_save`, not `after_save`.

Comment: What does `.reduce(0)` and `memo` do here? Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Ok thanks. Also I found some useful reference here: http://nishacodes.tumblr.com/post/80652377352/using-reduce-aka-inject-in-ruby